# How to window.alert error in API Requests Angular2?

Tags: angular, api, service, request

I have 2 API Requests, one Get and one Post and I want to print in screen the error message of these.
You can see the error of the GET Request  here:

```
401 UNAUTHORIZED
{
    "_status": "ERR",
    "_error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Please provide proper credentials"
    }
}
```

You can see the errors of the POST Request here:

```
422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY

Append
{
    "_status": "ERR",
    "_error": {
        "code": 422,
        "message": "Duplicate licence plate found during insertion."
    }
}

Remove
{
    "_status": "ERR",
    "_error": {
        "code": 422,
        "message": "Removal aborted. Licence plate not found in any or all of the given indexes."
    }
}

401 UNAUTHORIZED
{
    "_status": "ERR",
    "_error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Please provide proper credentials"
    }
}
```

My service is the following, but it doesn't print these messsages.

```
 getparkingDetails(): Observable<any>{

        console.log(this.token);
        const httpOptions = {


            headers: new HttpHeaders({

              'Content-Type':  'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer: ' + this.token,
            }),
          };


          return this.httpclient.get<any>("https://socialpark.iti.gr:8005/parking_sites/management", httpOptions).pipe(
            catchError(this.errorHandler));
        }

        errorHandler(error: any) {
          //if (error == 404)
          let errorMessage = '';
          if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
     // client-side error
          errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
          } else {
          // server-side error
           errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
           }

          window.alert(errorMessage);
         return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
          }



        addparkingDetails(parkingSite: any): Observable<any>{

          const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type':  'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer: ' + this.token,
            }),
          };
          return this.httpclient.post<any>(
            "https://socialpark.iti.gr:8005/parking_sites/management/updates",
            parkingSite,
            httpOptions).pipe(
              catchError(this.errorHandlerup));

            }

        errorHandlerup(error: any) {
          let errorMessage = '';
          if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
     // client-side error
          errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
          } else {
          // server-side error
           errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
           }

          window.alert(errorMessage);
         return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
          }
```

Comment: are you subscribing to addparkingDetails and getparkingDetails somewhere else because the call won't happen till you subscribe

Comment: yes I have a component wher I call them

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read full response to do that. In order to read full response use `observe:'response'` in httpclient.get like this:

```
getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
  return this.http.get<Config>(
    this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

You can find more information here: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response